# How to import data to sembast flutter?

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, nosql, sqflite

I'm developing mobile app on flutter and now selecting a database. I'm thinking about `sembast` (https://pub.dev/packages/sembast#-readme-tab-), but there is no information about importing (preloading) data to the database.
Does anyone know that? Should I add csv or json files with data to asset and then somehow load it into the database? In comparison, there is sqflite package from the same author (https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#-readme-tab-) and here I can add sqlite database to asset and then import it into the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sembast is not flutter only so there is no specific mention about asset file.

One solution is to preload data using the basic versioning system:
https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/blob/master/sembast/doc/open.md#preloading-data

Or to import data (reading an exported map from an asset file):
https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/blob/master/sembast/doc/storage_format.md#importexport